# Javascript setinterval within a period of times

Tags: javascript

I have this set of code:

```
var a = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Hello");
}
, 1000);
```

It will keep prompting hello in the command prompt each 1000 milliseconds, may i know if it is possible to only allow 5 prompts and stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `clearInterval` function let you remove any **interval** you declare, you just need to use a **counter** variable to check how many times the callback was performed.

**JS**

```
var i = 0;
var a = setInterval(function() {
  if (i === 5) {
    clearInterval(a);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Hello");
    i++;
  }
}
, 1000);
```

Comment: Probably better to use `i > 4` in case `i` is incremented elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out!
[Stops at 5 logs.](https://jsfiddle.net/nrvye9ac/2/)

```
var ctr = 0;
var a = setInterval(function()
{
if(ctr <= 4){
  console.log("Hello");
  ctr += 1;
  console.log(ctr); //stops at 5 logs
}else{
  clearInterval(a);
}

}
, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var b = 0  
var a = setInterval(function() {
      console.log("Hello");
      b++
      if (b === 5) {
        clearInterval(a);
      }
}, 1000);
```